# How to use Buffer.from in electron 21+

Tags: node.js, electron, v8

In Electron 21+, electron is using [v8 memory cage](https://www.electronjs.org/blog/v8-memory-cage). This is a fantastic move forward to reduce various bugs and enable performance of electron apps.

However, this seems to be causing an issue where I can't use `Buffer.from`. An example:

```
const buffer = Buffer.from(base64Image, `base64`)
```

This code throws an error:

```
[71637:1207/115131.065252:ERROR:node_bindings.cc(149)] Fatal error in V8: v8_ArrayBuffer_NewBackingStore When the V8 Sandbox is enabled, ArrayBuffer backing stores must be allocated inside the sandbox address space. Please use an appropriate ArrayBuffer::Allocator to allocate these buffers, or disable the sandbox.
```

Is there a way to keep the sandbox and keep using buffers?

Comment: Sounds like a question for the electron folks, on [their issue tracker](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues)? (after searching that first, of course, because while possible, it's unlikely you're the first person to run into this)

Comment: I think this might be the relevant issue https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/35801

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this will be fixed in Electron 21+ with [this PR](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/36625) (and its siblings)